# Java Bluetooth API

Tags: java, bluetooth, bluecove

I want to implement bluetooth communication on my final bachelor project, but I'm having a lot of doubts.

One of the requisites of this project is to have a Java application that can talk to the micro via Bluetooth. After a lot of research, I've found one that I think it's very good with a SPP profile, but I still have a lot of questions about it:

1. All the bluetooth on a PC implements the SPP profile stack?
2. If you need to develop a Java application that runs on every PC that implements the SPP stack, how would you do it?
3. We started by trying to use BlueCove and JavaBluetooth.org API, the first one runs great but I don't know if it's just on my PC and the second one sends an error (Stack not initialized). Which one would you use, and why?

My main goal with the project it's having some kind of software that runs on every PC with bluetooth (inside or as an external device) and running JVM, but I'm not sure if this APIs are the way.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> All the bluetooth on a PC implements the SPP profile stack?

Yes - Windows / Linux and Mac does.

> If you need to develop a Java
>   application that runs on every PC that
>   implements the SPP stack, how would
>   you do it?

As you are trying you can use a Java bluetooth api library like Bluecove or  alternatively natively try and open serial port on these platforms and thus have different versions of the application one for each platform.

> We started by trying to use BlueCove
>   and JavaBluetooth.org API, the first
>   one runs great but I don't know if
>   it's just on my PC and the second one
>   sends an error (Stack not
>   initialized). Which one would you use,
>   and why?

JavaBluetooth seems to be a full stack and based on very old 1.1 version of bluetooth spec.
Bluecove is just a Java library for bluetooth running over the native bluetooth implementations on Mac, Linux and PC.
I think Bluecove is probably the right way to go.

Comment: JavaBluetooth.org no longer exists, apparently.